# How to hide div when javasscript is turned off

Tags: javascript, html

I want to recommend the user to turn on js for a better browsing experience when js is turned off. I was thinking to do this with an absolute div and directly after i declare this, hide it through js (any other thoughts how to do this are welcome). However how can I let the user hide this div through a button when js is turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through CSS3 as shown in the solution of @kojiro. However you will also want to hide that div the next time the page loads because otherwise you'll be annoying your visitor. For this reason you may want to load within that div an iframe containing a form that would not only do the CSS3 trick but also on submit let the system know that the user does not want to display the div anymore. Your business logic then needs to record the user's IP when the iframe form is submitted. In PHP this this is for example

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Because you can't use sessions since .js is turned off, you'll have to record this in a database table. When the user loads the next page, record the user's IP and look it up in that table. When it exists, disable the div from parsing. F.e.

```
<?php
if (!$disableDiv)
echo "put the div";
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

With CSS3 you can use a form input [pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors#The_UI_element_states_pseudo-classes). For example, a div following a checked checkbox can be styled (or hidden) in a specific way. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXebt/) for a simple example.

```
<style>
:checked + div {
    display: none;
}
</style>
…
<input type="checkbox" name="foo">
<div id="hideme">Hide me by checking the checkbox</div>
```

Comment: That's a nifty little solution. +1

Comment: great way around JS events

Comment: Wow. Can you post a link to more info on this, I'm having trouble finding anything concrete regarding browser compatibility etc

Comment: @stephenmurdoch um, what info would you like? [Here's a post on CSS3 support](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-support-ie9/) that indicates it should work in IE9, but I can confirm it doesn't work in IE8 and earlier.

Comment: @kojiro, thanks, I didn't know about `:checked`, I see you can only use it on radio buttons and checkboxes, which makes sense

Comment: @stephenmurdoch you can also accomplish something similar with an anchor and the `:target` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to "hide" a div programatically without js unless you reload the page with a post or get request to your server.

You can use the `noscript` tag if you really want to.

```
<noscript>FOO BAR</noscript>
```

But there is no way to hide it without javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The div is a good idea.

Instead of hiding the div, just create a link to direct the user to a page that does not have the div in it.